# C# Selenium: Send keys ""{ENTER}"" not working

Tags: c#, selenium, sendkeys

Trying to paste file path in windows file upload, when I pass filepath in sendwait it does not paste entire data all the time,so was trying with the below but enter key is not working in this case, not sure why. Kindly help.

Code:

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject(FilePath,false,2,2000);
SendKeys.SendWait("^{V}");
SendKeys.SendWait(@"{ENTER}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to send the path, straight to the input element? That is the best way to upload a file, using Selenium.

Example:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("upload")).SendKeys(path);
```

You're finding the input element, which is responsible for upload and sending a path to it.